# vector-valued function of the given curve from two given points

Tags: vector-spaces

So I have to fin a vector-valued function of the portion of the parabola $z = 4y^2$ on the yz-plane from the point $(0, −1, 4)$ to $(0, 2, 16)$

I don't even know where to start from this, if i get the vector function as $r=<0,t,4t^2>$, what do i do with the given points?

Comment: Let $y(t) = t$, then $z(t) = 4 t^2$. then you have the function $t \mapsto (0,t,4 t^2)$, which maps the interval $[-1,2]$ into the curve given above.

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH thank you so much

Comment: You are very welcOOOOOOOme.